# Cannot add polyfill for URL.createObjectURL in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add polyfill for `URL.createObjectURL` in my Node.js application. I am using this package as polyfill:

https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill/blob/341221207263c9214e794fc3eaf221a71c596d29/url-polyfill.js#L456

I include the polyfill like this:

```
global.URL = require('url-polyfill')
```

But still, I am still getting the error which `TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function`. Am I polyfilling the wrong way?

Comment: What do you expect a blob URL to do in node? There is no Blob nor MediaSource it could be made from.

Comment: Note, Node 16 supports the WHATWG version of URL... you just have to importe it from Node's url module https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/url.html#the-whatwg-url-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as @Kaiido point out, the polyfill only patched `new URL()` and `new URLSearchParams()` usage, but not `URL.createObjectURL`, so this won't solve the problem.
>
> `URL.createObjectURL` polyfill seems hard to patch in Node.js, as the output url is supposed to be consumed by other Web APIs. There is not much related npm packages.
>
> A way to use full Web API in Node.js may be just use [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) or similar headless Browser, and run your Web part of code inside. Or try [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) which allow some context mix between Node.js and Web.

From the code: https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill/blob/34122120/url-polyfill.js#L464

Seems like this is a webpacked polyfill for Node.js,
and you should just do:

```js
console.log(URL.createObjectURL) // nothing

require('url-polyfill')

console.log(URL.createObjectURL) // polyfilled, if the code works in `url-polyfill`, but in this case will not
```

Note: in Node `global.URL` can just be `URL`,
if you do not defined a dup-named variable in same scope.

Comment: I don't think this will work either. If you check the polyfill's code all this method does is to call the original `global.URL.createObjectURL`, which is undefined in node.

Comment: @Kaiido I think your right, this is the wrong polyfill from the start, correct the usage alone won't solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am trying to polyfill  `URL.createObjectURL` for using this package in node. Would you mind take a look for me please?

https://github.com/developit/greenlet

Comment: I think developit/greenlet is intended to be used in Web only, and the `URL.createObjectURL` is not a easy patch in nodejs.
For your use case maybe a Nodejs Worker package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool can help?

Comment: And beware both seems can't handle function that refers upvalues (closures), so maybe use `child_process.spawn` to run another script file, and get the result by file or stdout can also work in your case.

Comment: For upvalues are you referring to free variables, where they are used in a function but not passed as argument?

Comment: Btw @dr-js thank you for your recommendation. `Workerpool` looks solid to me!

Comment: @JohnWinston Yes, upvalues means value referenced in function, but created in outer scope,
I think most of the worker package will use `func.toString()` on the function you passed in,
then send to worker, but that way the context is lost.

Writing long functions that works after `toString` is quite a different experience.
So often it's better to just pass a path to a script and later `require` it.